# Iterating over sublists in a sliding slope function gives index error

Tags: python-2.7, loops, indexing, linear-regression, nested-lists

I'm rather new to Python so bear with me. I'm trying to write a bit of code that will calculate a sliding slope for each frame of a movie, where each frame is a sublist in a larger list. I want to calculate the slopes for every n number of values ("width" in the code) to produce a new list of lists with the slopes for each frame in their own sublist. 
This code worked with six values in each sublist but when I run it with more numbers in each sublist it gives me the "list index out of range" error in reference to YSD.append(SlidingSlope(smoothedarrayX,array_y[:][k],3)).

Here's the code:

```
def SlidingSlope(array_x,array_y,width):
arrayofslopes=[]
for i in range(0, len(array_x)):
        x=array_x[i:i+width]
        y=array_y[i:i+width]
        arrayofslopes.append(sp.stats.linregress(x,y))           
return arrayofslopes

def YFramesSlopes(array_y):
YSlopedata=[]    
for j in range(0,len(array_y)):
    YSD=[]        
    YSlopedata.append(YSD)       
    for k in range(0,len(array_y[j])):
        YSD.append(SlidingSlope(smoothedarrayX,array_y[:][k],3))
return YSlopedata
```

So I guess the overarching issue I'm struggling with is how to make this sliding slope function iterate over the values in the Y sublists using the same list of X values, if that makes sense. Any help is greatly appreciated.